# Javascript countdown table not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

I am making a website for a school project. My idea is to have a table with multiple countdowns counting down (yes) to different cricket tournaments. I got the multiple countdowns in table code from another thread but it won't display for me when I load my site.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<Html>
    <head>
        <title>CCC</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cccstyle.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mr+De+Haviland&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--top of the page title--> 
        <div id="title">
            <h1>The CTC</h1>
            <h3>Cricket Tournament Countdown</h3>
        </div id="title">
        <noscript id="countdown">Sorry, you need JavaScript enabled to view the count downs</noscript>
        <script src="table.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
  // data is an array of objects, each representing one of your categories.
  // Each category has a .title to store its title and a .counters that
  // stores an object for each counter in that category.
  var data = [
    {
      title: 'LEAGUES',
      counters: [
        // Each counter has a .title and a .date that is parsed by new Date()
        {
          title: 'IPL',
          date: 'September 19, 2020'
        },
        {
          title: 'BBL',
          date: 'December 3, 2020'
        },
        {
          title: 'CPL',
          date: 'December 3, 2020'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'ICC TOURNAMENTS',
      counters: [
        {
          title: "Women's Cricket World Cup",
          date: 'February 6, 2021'
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  // this reduce generates the table
  let table = data.reduce((acc, category, categoryIndex) => {
  return acc + `<tr><td colspan="6" class="category">${category.title}</td></tr>` +
  category.counters.reduce((acc, counter, index) => {
    return acc + `<tr id="counter-${categoryIndex}-${index}">
    <td>${counter.title}</td>
    <td>${counter.date}</td>
    <td class="days"></td>
    <td class="hours"></td>
    <td class="minutes"></td>
    <td class="seconds"></td>
    </tr>`;
    }, '');
  }, '<table class="countdown"><tr><th>Event</th><th>Date</th><th>Days</th><th>Hours</th><th>Minutes</th><th>Seconds</th></tr>');
  table += '</table>';
  
  // insert the table after the noscript tag
  document.getElementById('countdown').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', table);
  
  // generate a flat list of counters
  let counters = data.reduce((acc, category, categoryIndex) => {
  return acc.concat(category.counters.reduce((counterAcc, counter, index) => {
      return counterAcc.concat([{
        // counters will be an array of the objects we generate here.
        // node contains a reference to the tr element for this counter
        node: document.getElementById(`counter-${categoryIndex}-${index}`),
        // date is the date for this counter parsed by Date and then converted
        // into a timestamp
        date: (new Date(counter.date)).getTime()
        }]);
      }, []));
  }, []);
  
  const msSecond = 1000,
    msMinute = msSecond * 60,
    msHour = msMinute * 60,
    msDay = msHour * 24;
  let intervalId;
  
  function updateCounters () {
    counters.forEach((counter, counterIndex) => {
    let remaining = counter.date - Date.now(),
      node = counter.node;
    let setText = (selector, text) => node.querySelector(selector).textContent = text;
  
    if (remaining > 0) {
      setText('.days', Math.floor(remaining / msDay));
      remaining %= msDay;
      setText('.hours', Math.floor(remaining / msHour));
      remaining %= msHour;
      setText('.minutes', Math.floor(remaining / msMinute));
      remaining %= msMinute;
      setText('.seconds', Math.floor(remaining / msSecond));
    } else {
      // make sure we don't accidentally display negative numbers if a timer
      // firing late returns a past timestamp (or the data contains a past date)
      setText('.days', 0);
      setText('.hours', 0);
      setText('.minutes', 0);
      setText('.seconds', 0);
  
      // This countdown has reached 0 seconds, stop updating it.
      counters.splice(counterIndex, 1);
      // no more counters? Stop the timer
      if (counters.length === 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }
    });
  }
  // display counters right away without waiting a second
  updateCounters();
  intervalId = setInterval(updateCounters, 1000);
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #00002e;
}
div.title {
    text-align: center;
}
script {
    display: inline;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #edf;
}
.category {
    font-weight: bold;
}
td, th {
    padding: .5em;
}
.days, .hours, .minutes, .seconds {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Your code is malformed. You are not closing the brackcets correctly.

Comment: Did you check the console and elements in the browsers inspector for errors?

Comment: Check the console for errors. Copy and paste the JSON into something like jsonlint.com to see where the errors are in that, but you're definitely missing a comma and have an extra bracket in the JSON.

Comment: @Carlos1232 which ones are wrong and how do I close them correctly?

Comment: @ColinG I fixed the missing comma but got an error at `title: "Women's Cricket World Cup",
          date: 'February 6, 2021'
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

`                          Saying "property assignment expected. Sorry only started doing this a month or two ago for school should've chosen a much easier website to do.